Generalisation of the idea of decomposition into symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices
We know that a $n\times n$ matrix $A_{ij}$ can be decomposed into :
$$B_{ij}=\frac12 (A_{ij} + B_{ji})$$
$$C_{ij} =\frac12 (A_{ij} - B _{ji})$$
I made a generalisation of this idea to rank $k$ tensors. e.g. for a rank 3 tensor $A_{ijk}$, we define :
$$B_{ijk}=\frac13 (A_{ijk}+A_{jki}+A_{kij})$$
$$C_{ijk} =\frac13 ( A_{ijk}+\omega A_{jki} +\omega ^2 A_{kij})$$
$$D_{ijk}=\frac13 (A_{ijk} + \omega ^2 A_{jki} + \omega ^4  A_{kij})$$
where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity. $\omega = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$.
We obtain $B+C+D=A$
Similarly, for a rank $k$ tensor $A_{i_1 i_2, ... i_k}$, we take the $k$th root of unity $\omega =e^{i\frac{2\pi}{k}}$ and define a decomposition of $A$ into $k$ matrices which are computed using an analogous sum over cyclic permutations of the indices $i_1, i_2...., i_k$
Is there a name for this decomposition method? And does it have applications?

The vector space of "rank $k$" tensors has an action by the symmetric group $S_k$ on the indices, which you can restrict to the cyclic group $\mathbf{Z}/k$ permuting the indices by (powers of) a long cycle. Any $\mathbf{C}$ representation of $\mathbf{Z}/k$ is a direct sum of subspaces where $\mathbf{Z}/k$ acts by $\zeta_k^i$, where $\zeta_k$ is a primitive $k$th root of unity (since the only irreducible representations of this group are the characters $\zeta_k^i \in \mathbf{C}^\times$), and the maps you write down are the projections to these subspaces.
I don't have a name for these in general (other than projector/projection) but they also remind me of polarization identities. See also Maschke's theorem and related facts for more general formulas.

Thanks for the links. Also, is this particular idea used anywhere in math? I mean specifically the idea where we decompose tensors like in the post

The general idea of splitting a representation into copies of different irreducibles has applications but I don't know anything more relevant for this specific situation.
